# Create struct for vertex buffer on DX9

Tags: c++, directx, directx-9, vertex, vertex-buffer

I have a huge problem in my DirectX project.
I need to make struct for vertexbuffer..

```
CUSTOMVERTEX vertices[] =
{
    { 2.5f, -3.0f, 0.0f, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(0, 0, 255), },
    { 0.0f, 3.0f, 0.0f, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(0, 255, 0), },
    { -2.5f, -3.0f, 0.0f, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(255, 0, 0), },
};
```

But how do I do that in a loop?
I need to make huge field of triangles(3d terrain). So,
I tried something like this:

```
void Field_Generation::Field_Generate(int X, int Y, int Z)
{
int zeme[X][Y];
int n=0;

for (int i=0;i < X;i++)
{
    for (int j=0;i < Y;j++)
    {
        zeme[i][j] = rand() % Z;
    }
}

for (int i=0;i < X;i++)
{
    for (int j=0;i < Y;j++)
    {
        int color1= rand() % 255;
        int color2= rand() % 255;
        int color3= rand() % 255;

        n++;
    CUSTOMVERTEX verticles[n] = {{i,j,zeme[i][j],D3DCOLOR_XRGB(color1,color2,color3),}};


    }
}
}
```

But this ain't working for me. :( I can't figure out how to do that. Help please. Thank you.

Comment: Try to draw it on a paper and you'll figure it out ;)

Comment: What's your problem? compile error? data incorrect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of problems with the code you posted.

First of all, this won't work:

```
int zeme[X][Y];
```

You can't create a dynamic array this way. Although there are various ways to do it, I would recommend using `std::vector` so at the top of your source make sure you include the right header:

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
```

Then you can define your `zeme` like this:

```
vector<vector<int> > zeme(X, vector<int>(Y, 0));
```

Now you can access your elements using `zeme[x][y]` as you do already.

Next you need to create an array to hold your custom vertex data, and again you can use a `std::vector`. This should be defined as a class member or a global variable rather than being defined inside your function. Something like:

```
std::vector<CUSTOMVERTEX> m_pVertices;
```

Then, inside your loop, initialise each entry like this:

```
CUSTOMVERTEX pVertex = {i, j, zeme[i][j], D3DCOLOR_XRGB(color1,color2,color3) };
m_pVertices.push_back(pVertex);
```

Later, when you need to pass a pointer to your array of vertices to DirectX for drawing, use this syntax to get a pointer to the start of the data:

```
CUSTOMVERTEX *pData = &m_pVertices[0];
```

(Note that in C++11 there are alternative ways of handling all of the above)

Another alternative, if you already have an array of `CUSTOMVERTEX` is to initialise each component inside the loop. So, assuming your `CUSTOMVERTEX` has a structure like this (I'm guessing because you don't show it):

```
struct CUSTOMVERTEX 
{
    float x, y, z;
    D3DCOLOR nCol;
};
```

Then, inside your loop, you could initialise each entry like this (you need to use whatever names are defined in your structure):

```
verticles[n].x = i;
verticles[n].y = j;
verticles[n].z = zeme[i][j];
verticles[n].nCol = D3DCOLOR_XRGB(color1,color2,color3);
```

So, you assign each value to a member of the struct rather than trying to assign the whole struct in one hit like I did in the first example.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the value of a struct by setting each of it's component, like this.

```
struct Person
{
    int age;
    string name;
};

Person person[2];

person[0].age = 20;
person[0].name = "zdd";

person[1].age = 30;
person[1].name = "ddz";
```